# InStr not working due to a loop on the Dim

Tags: excel, vba

I am slowly building off this code as I'd like to learn VBA for future use. The purpose of this part of my code is to see if one cell's value is contained inside another sheet in the same workbook's cell. If this is true then I would like to mark column 10 of the same row in Worksheets("FDSA") as "ok" and write nothing if it is not.

```
Sub test1()

Dim Str As String
Dim Search As String

Str = Cells(2, 5).Value
Search = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(2, 5).Value


    If InStr(Search, Str) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(2, 10).Value = "ok"
    End If

End Sub
```

I got an answer yesterday that helped a lot (top). I am now trying to make a loop for that code. Here it is now (bottom).

```
Sub test1()

For X = 2 To 5
For Y = 2 To 5

Dim Str As String
Dim Search As String

Str = Cells(X, 5).Value
Search = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 5).Value


    If InStr(Search, Str) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 10).Value = "ok"

    Else
        Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 10).Value = ""

    End If

Next Y
Next X

End Sub
```

I ran a test to see if it worked and it did not. I made it so that cells(5,5) was not contained inside of Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(Y, 5) and it still wrote the ok. After doing some research I have concluded that the Dim storage might be the problem(It is using the value of the initials which due match).I tried using ReDim and clear but could not run the code. Thank you for your help, please let me know if you need more explanation.

-Alexis M.

Comment: Have you tried moving the Dim's to outside the loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only want one loop:

```
Sub test1()
Dim Str As String
Dim Search As String
Dim X as Long

For X = 2 To 5

Str = Cells(X, 5).Value
Search = Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(X, 5).Value


    If InStr(Search, Str) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(X, 10).Value = "ok"

    Else
        Worksheets("FDSA").Cells(X, 10).Value = ""

    End If

Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: I wrote the Y in there as a place holder. It will differ from the likeness of x after I solve the Dim problem. Thank you for your response but it still marks the cell as "ok" when it is suppose to be blank as it does not contain the value.

Comment: With respect, that can't happen. "ok" will only be put in the cell if the value in `str` is found in `Search`. I suggest you step through the code and check what the values actually are. And now I'm even more confused as you marked this as the answer!

Comment: I wrote the Y in there as a place holder. It will differ from the likeness of x after I solve the Dim problem. Thank you for your response it seems to have fixed it. Was it the Dim X as long? I ask because I will need the Y loop later. Thanks! Yes pardon this was correct.